# Multi-config/multi-platform build for CUDA using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cuda

I've had a bit of a fight with CMake lately trying to get it to generate project files for Debug and Release targets on different platforms involving Cuda. The Cuda version I'm using is 9.1 on Windows and Linux. CMake version is 3.9 on Windows and 3.10 on Linux.

The problem is actually simple, because I can generate the builds on Windows if *nvcc* gets passed the `"-DEBUG"` flag correctly. However, I cannot seem to pass the flag correctly by configuration automatically. I tried using `CMAKE_NVCC_FLAGS_CONFIG`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CONFIG` with `CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS` set to `ON/OFF`, switching `CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP` to `ON/OFF` did not help either. Setting the flag using expression generators to set directory properties using `set_directory_property`, or as an option to `cuda_add_executable` also did not work.

Here's the gist of my cmake script:

```
# CMake entry point
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9.1)

set( APP_NAME example-CUDA )

find_package(XYZ)
find_package(CUDA)  # not required according to 1st-class status in CMake3 .8+

enable_language(CUDA)
set(CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD ON)

set(SRC_EXAMPLE "main.cpp" "gj.cu"  "gj.cuh")
SOURCE_GROUP(Example FILES ${SRC_EXAMPLE})

set(SRC_BUILD_FILES ${SRC_EXAMPLE})

# note: similar stuff for linux ommitted..
if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "Windows")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4 /WX /sdl- -Zm256")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MD")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /we4146 /we4308 /we4532 /we4533 /we4700 /we4703 /we4789 /we4995 /we4996")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /INCREMENTAL")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MP")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /we4146 /we4308 /we4532 /we4533 /we4700 /we4703 /we4789 /we4995 /we4996")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /W4 /WX /sdl- -Zm256")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /Zi")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /D_DEBUG" CACHE STRING "compile flags debug" FORCE)
endif()

# cuda 9 flags for max compatibility ( note: no more sm 20!)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-arch=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=compute_70")

include_directories(SYSTEM  ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

#set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP ON) 
#set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)

#set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}   " -D_DEBUG ")             # works, but hadcoded config :(

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG}    " -D_DEBUG ") # fails, not picked up..

#cuda_add_executable (${APP_NAME} ${SRC_EXAMPLE} OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"-DEBUG">) #fails, generator not run

cuda_add_executable (${APP_NAME} ${SRC_EXAMPLE})
target_link_libraries (${APP_NAME} PUBLIC CUDA XYZ)
```

The error I get in VS2015 (and I'm also using 2017) is the typical _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL not being correct, implying that one of the compilation units was not properly passed the -DEBUG flag and the linker sees rebug and release modules mixed. The module built by nvcc.exe is internally passed on for compilation by cl.exe for non-cuda code bits, except that all the _DEBUG configuration flags are missing. I've read through FindCUDA.cmake to find something interesting but it's almost impossible to tell what is working and what is not.

I'm obviously missing something, but what? Any workarounds?

UPDATE 1:  I also set the following way earlier in the CMakeLists.txt hierarchy:

```
project (MyLittleBigProject)

# Set default build type
set(PROJECT_CONFIGURATIONS      Debug Release               CACHE TYPE INTERNAL FORCE)
if(DEFINED CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING "Build configs: ${PROJECT_CONFIGURATIONS}")
else()
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Build configs: ${PROJECT_CONFIGURATIONS}")
endif()
```

Comment: Is there any chance some code is compiled with a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler, in which case you would need to tweak `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` as well? Also, do you set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and do you call `project()` at some point?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @piwi. Yes 'project()' is called way up in the hierarchy of CMakeLists.txt files. Also this particular example sits with one of many cpp examples, all build fine and I never set any specific _C_ flags. I also do set 'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE', I updated my answer with this info above. Thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of things working together to create this issue, the largest one being the fact that support for VS2017 was simply not there.

That said, I could still get it to work for other compilers correctly by building my own Cmake dummy target to wrap all the CUDA library dependencies and build settings. I started from the existing Find_XXX CMake scripts for CUDA I could find, and added the following section after the macros (a trick I'm using with almost any of my dependencies). This section is actually not strictly necessary since CMake apparently does the same for you behind the scenes, but it works also in case something goes wrong with that automagic, with the bonus that you have full control over what is happening.

```
set(API "CUDA")
if(NOT TARGET "${API}")     
    if (CUDA_cudart_static_LIBRARY)     # we assume at least cuda 5.5+
        add_custom_target("Generate${API}" DEPENDS  "${CUDA_cudart_static_LIBRARY}" )        
        add_library(            "${API}"            STATIC          IMPORTED                                GLOBAL )      
        set_property(TARGET     "${API}"            PROPERTY        IMPORTED_LOCATION                       "${CUDA_cudart_static_LIBRARY}")
        set_property(TARGET     "${API}"            PROPERTY        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES                "${CUDA_LIBRARIES}")        

        set_property(TARGET     "${API}"            PROPERTY        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES           "${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}"   )
        set_property(TARGET     "${API}"            PROPERTY        FOLDER                                  "APIGenerators"     )
        set_property(TARGET     "Generate${API}"    PROPERTY        FOLDER                                  "APIGenerators"     )
        add_dependencies(       "${API}"            "Generate${API}")
    else()
        add_library(            "${API}"            INTERFACE       IMPORTED                                GLOBAL )
    endif() 
endif()
```

So now that you've got your own CUDA Find_Package call for CUDA ready, yhou can go ahead and set up a cmake to create your project by simply calling find_package(CUDA). CMake recognises CUDA 'automatically', so the linking is actually implicit. Here's how I set up some variables for the NVCC compile step that is called behind the scenes:

```
enable_language(CUDA)
set(CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD ON)

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-I=${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR} ")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-I=${GLEW_INCLUDE_PATH} ")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-I=${YOUR_INCLUDE_DIRS} ")
# cuda 9 flags for max compatibility ( no more sm 20!)
if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "Windows")
    #set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}   "-arch=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode=arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=compute_70")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-arch=sm_30")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_62,code=sm_62")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=compute_70")
else()      
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    "-arch=sm_30")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS   ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}    " -std=c++11")
endif()
```

Now you can turn off the CUDA flags for including host flags since you've set them yourself, and specify some related compile definitions that were required in my case.

```
set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP OFF)
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
target_compile_definitions(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"_DEBUG ">)
target_compile_definitions(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE "_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED")
target_compile_definitions(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE "_FORCE_INLINES")
target_compile_definitions(${APP_NAME} PRIVATE "__STRICT_ANSI__")

set_target_properties(${APP_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

Last but not least, switch to C++11 compilation, because otherwise your compiler may get confused by all the < > template-like auto type constructions.

```
set_target_properties(${APP_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

Hope this helps for some of you out there. If you know how to get it to work on VS2017 without too much hassle please leave a comment!

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of CUDA/NVCC, but looking at the documentation of [`FindCUDA`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html), here are a couple of things you can try:

- Pass Debug flags through `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG`, because the documentation of `CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` states that by default, `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` is used, not `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`,
- Pass Debug flags through `cuda_add_executable()`: the documentation indicates that it calls `cuda_wrap_srcs()` where you can pass specific flags with `OPTIONS DEBUG ...`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried the second option, and for the first idea I tried to use CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG, which supposedly sets flags for the C compiler in debug mode. I'll get back to you soon on using CMAKE_C_COMPILER_DEBUG instead..

Comment: @StarShine `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_DEBUG` is an error from my part sorry, I meant `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` (I edited my answer).

Comment: Ok, as for the second option, using cuda_wrap_srcs() implies that you set each and every setting yourself. That is based on FindCUDA.cmake which has been deprecated in favour of using the now elevated 1st-class citizen status of CUDA language in CMake, except that unfortunately it does not seem to work as it should for different configurations.

Comment: @StarShine Then sorry I cannot help you much with your problem :-( However, what you can do is prospect the files in the `CMakeFiles` directories, as usually the commands invoked are stored in files in these directories, as well as the `CMakeOutput.log` files. Maybe you will find clues on what is going on...

Comment: Yes that is an idea I can try, thanks. Hopefully @ComicSansMS or one of the other CMake gurus can shed some light..